# Question about the proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Theorem:
Let  $\phi: G \rightarrow H$ be a group homomorphism.
Then $\operatorname{Ker}(\phi)$ is a normal subgroup of G. $\phi(G)$ is a subgroup of H and the map
$\phi'$: $G/\operatorname{Ker}(\phi) \rightarrow \phi(G)$,
$a\operatorname{Ker}(\phi)\mapsto \phi(a)$ is a group isomorphism.

My question relates to the part where it is shown that $\phi'$ is surjective. From the proof:
Because of $\phi'(G/N)=\phi(G)$, $\phi'$ is obviously surjective.
So why do we know that $\phi'(G/N)=\phi(G)$ holds?

Comment: I'm assuming $N = \ker(\phi)$?

Comment: @Randall yes, my bad

Comment: The definition of $\phi'$ should be $a\ker(\phi)\mapsto \phi(a)$, not "$\mapsto \phi(G)$". Using that, the claim is indeed obvious since it means that $\phi'(a\ker(\phi)) = \phi(a)$ for all $a\in G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything in $\phi(G)$ takes the form $\phi(a)$ for $a \in G$, and the coset $aN$ will map to $\phi(a)$.  Check the definition of $\phi'$.

Comment: But isn't G/N:={aN:a in G}, and if there exists a,b in G such that aN=bN, then the set G/N should just contain one of them?

Comment: That isn't a question of it being onto, though.

Comment: If $aN = bN$ then $G/N$ contains both since they're the same thing.  Also, $G/N$ contains ALL cosets of the form $aN$.

Comment: @WanyM Talking about "just one of them" is very misleading when there is just one thing. Note that $aN$ and $bN$ are just two names for the same thing when $aN=bN$. But this is not related to surjectivity of $\phi'$ at all.

Comment: I think i got it. Because aN=bN, b $\in$ aN so there exists a q $\in$ 
N such that b=a*q. So in the end $\phi(b)=\phi(aq)=\phi(a)*\phi(q)=\phi(a)*e$

Comment: You seem to be arguing something different, like possibly the well-defined-ness of $\phi'$.

Comment: @ Randall Maybe there was my problem. I thought if aN=bN and a $\neq$ b. Then $\phi^{'}$ could not map bN on $\phi(b)$, because  $\phi^{'}$ already mapped bN=aN on $\phi(a)$